# SVN: A file won't update

Tags: svn

Is it possible in SVN to run

```
svn update
svn diff
```

and get an output from svn diff, without getting any conflicts in the update stage?

In particular, I have an empty file in the svn directory. On the server it's a long and complicated file. svn diff-ing shows me that all the lines in this file were erased; however, svn updating changes nothing. What should I do to restore the file and all the other files like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to follow your question given that you aren't using Subversion's terminology, but if you want to discard uncommitted changes in your working copy you need to use the [revert](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) subcommand.

Comment: This does the trick, thanks. What terminology I should have used? I'm used to working with git, not svn.

Comment: Well, "discard uncommitted changes" would have been fine ;-P - Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first (and more general) part of your question: yes.

You can have some file modifications on your local machine, let's say at the beginning of the file. An `update` could merge in some changes, let's say at the end of the file. If those two areas don't overlap, you would not get any conflicts. Still, your changes are uncommitted, so `diff`'ing the file would still show them and a subsequent `commit` would commit them, of course.